# Header Floated Left In IE only, should be centered

Tags: internet-explorer, css-float

Could some one kindly take a look at the code for http://www.weavinginfluence.com/

In IE only the header floats left but it should be centered. I've been racking my brain for two-hours now and cannot seem to get it unstuck.

Any help if greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the below line from your custom css that is applied for inner class:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: That's a bit of a conundrum as box-sizing is set to border-box globally to every single element and that will not change. If I try to just set the CSS to that one particular element to content-box, the default value, it does not change anything. It seems there is an issue with overflow: hidden, but that is necessary to force the height and display the white background.